# How to make an update extension

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Let consider a extension formed with this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.foo()
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
RAISE NOTICE 'foo v.1.0';
END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

This is `myextension--1.0.sql`

And this is `myextension.control`

```
# extension prueba
comment = 'prueba para updatear extensiones'
default_version = '1.0'
module_pathname = '$libdir/unaccent'
relocatable = true
```

Doing

```
CREATE EXTENSION myextension
```

All is all right.

Now, I need to update this function and add another one.

It will be `myextension--2.0.sql`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.foo()
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
RAISE NOTICE 'foo v.2.0';
END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;   

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.bar()
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
RAISE NOTICE 'bar v.1.0';
END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

<s>Then, I don't know how I must to prepare it for get an updated extension. I have been watching any extensions installed with postgres, like [unnaccent](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/tree/master/contrib/unaccent) but I don't understand the mechanism of update. Looks as if `unaccent--1.1.sql` has all the functions (the new ones and the updated functions) and `unaccent--1.0--1.1.sql` has the instructions for update the existing functions located in `unaccent--1.1.sql`</s>

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

Following the answers, I have created `myextension--1.0--2.0.sql` with those statements:

```
ALTER FUNCTION foo() PARALLEL SAFE;
```

Also, I've changed the default version in `myextension.control`

```
default_version = '2.0'
```

But if I do:

```
ALTER EXTENSION myextension UPDATE;
```

Postgres tell me that I have made a succesfull updated, and I have 2.0 version, but neither `foo()` is updated nor `bar()` is created.

Comment: See here [Extensions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/extend-extensions.html) in particular [Updating](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/extend-extensions.html) and the section after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unaccent--1.0--1.1.sql` has the SQL statements to update version 1.0 installed by `unaccent--1.0.sql`.

`CREATE EXTENSION` automatically finds a sequence of SQL scripts to run to install the desired version. If there is no "base" SQL script that installs the desired version, it will start with a lower versio and then apply "delta" scripts until it has the desired version.

Comment: Thank you. I think that I got it, but no. I have modified the question.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo. I meant 1.0--1.1 modifies the installation from 1.0. If it doesn't work for you the problem must be something else. Try your scripts by hand first.